# Dynamically drawing polygons in Google map

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am new to android. I've been trying to apply a field of view to my current location in google map. The image shows a FOV on Google map in iOS.

[image]

So basically I did a similar thing by adding 5 triangles with different alpha in order to make  the whole fov a gradiant.

[image]

I have to update this fov according to azimuth of the device, so I remove those triangles ,recompute them and add them again.

```
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        if(triangles[i]!=null){
            triangles[i].remove();
        }
    //triangles=null;

        la = mvalues[0]-hang/2;
        lx = lon+i*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(la))/2775;
        ly = lat+i*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(la))/2775;
        ra = mvalues[0]+hang/2;
        rx = lon+i*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(ra))/2775;
        ry = lat+i*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(ra))/2775;

        triangles[i] = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(new LatLng(lat,lon), new LatLng(ly,lx), new LatLng(ry,rx)).strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT).fillColor(Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 50)));

    }
```

The fov is always blinking, and gc_concurrent always happens. Is it possible to make it not blinking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes

According to the Google documentation above.

You shall update the shape by calling 
Polygon.setPoints [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon?hl=zh-TW#setPoints%28java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E%29)

rather than remove/add.

Hope this would help

Comment: Thanks, it also do the trick but FOV is still blinking. Maybe some other component should be checked instead of this.